# What is rotating my haproxy logs?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, logrotate

I have a haproxy logrotate configuration file in `/etc/logrotate.d/haproxy` that looks like this:

```
"var/log/haproxy.log" "/var/log/haproxy-status.log" {
  daily
  size 250M
  rotate 1
  create 644 root root
  missingok
  compress
  notifyempty
  copytruncate
}
```

which is not working. I have proved this by running `logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/haproxy` which gives me `skipping "/var/log/haproxy.log" because parent directory has insecure permissions` - I have a work in progress to fix this, my question is different.

However, my logs are still being rotated by something else. Where can I find what might be rotating those logs?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is just a typo.

Note that in your configuration you have: `"var/log/haproxy.log"`

This is a relative path and should be changed to be an absolute path:

`"/var/log/haproxy.log"`

So finally your config file should be:

```
"/var/log/haproxy.log" "/var/log/haproxy-status.log" {
  daily
  size 250M
  rotate 1
  create 644 root root
  missingok
  compress
  notifyempty
  copytruncate
}
```

Anything that rotates logs is located in `/etc/logrotate.conf`, which in turn includes `/etc/logrotate.d` directory. Anything matching your haproxy path is rotating your logs.

Answer (score 0):

To check if Your log is rotated use following command

```
cat /var/lib/logrotate/status |grep haproxy
```

or (other systems)

```
cat /var/lib/logrotate.status |grep haproxy
```

If You find it, look at `/etc/logrotate.conf` and `/etc/logrotate.d/*` files.

```
grep -r log /etc/logrotate*
```

Comment: I know is being rotated, but I don't know what's rotating it...

Comment: OK. Please show output of logrotate status command and output of `grep -r log /etc/logrotate*` command